# On loading web page with Firefox is not displayed as normal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to reduce the height webpage,
So that entire page will be exposed except a part of the purple color on the bottom page.
I think that the purple color part of the bottom page is html tag
And he unnecessary.
many thanks.
link:http://www.centerwow.com/window1/window/window.html

css code:

```
html{
height:0px;
}


body {
    //overflow:hidden;
    font-family:Palatino Linotype;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #6000CC;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height:600px;

}
 .insidWindow {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffFFFF;
    margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top:-515px;
    width:52.5%;
}
h2 {


    color: #443333;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 7px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
}
.lineAzure{
    background: #0066ff;
    line-height: 7px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height:15px;
}
#lineAzurebotom {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #880000;
    line-height: 11px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -516px;
}
#leftcolumn_s {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DDFF00;
    height: 115px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 360px;
    width: 88%;
}
#rightcolumn_s{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DDFF00;
    height: 115px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 360px;
    width: 88%;
}

#chatRead {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #88FF00;
    line-height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -520px;
    width: 55%;
}
#chatWrite {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #88FFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -520px;
    width: 55%;
}

#lineYelow{
    background: #00FFFF;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #00ffff;

    line-height: 7px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

    height:35px
}
#wrapMein{
    background: green;
    //overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0px 5px 20px 5px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    height:530px;
}
.column {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DDFFFF;
    height: 505px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    width: 20%;
}
.rcolumn{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ddffff;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width:20%;
    height:495px;
    position:relative;
    top:-528px;
    float:right;

}
.ui-wrapper {
    border: 2px solid #70A029;
}

.ui-resizable {
    position: relative;
}

.ui-resizable-e {
    background: url("../pic/resizable-e.gif") repeat scroll right center transparent;
    cursor: e-resize;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 6px;
}
.ui-resizable-handle {
    display: none;
    font-size: 0.1px;
    position: absolute;
}
.ui-resizable-s {
    background: url("../pic/resizable-s.gif") repeat scroll center top transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: s-resize;
    height: 6px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.ui-resizable-se {
    background: url("../pic/resizable-se.gif") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: se-resize;
    height: 9px;
    right: 0;
    width: 9px;
}
```

html code:

```
<h2>this is body background.</h2>
<div class="lineAzure">this is div class lineAzure </div>
<div id="lineYelow">this is div id  YineYelow</div>
<div id="wrapMein">
<div class="lineAzure" style="margin: 0px 22.6% 0px 22.6%;" "width:52.5%" >this div classlineAzurespnbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</div>
<div id="leftcolumn" class="column">here is div id = leftcolumn
<div id="leftcolumn_s">here is div id = leftcolumn_s</div>
</div>
<div id="rightcolumn" class="rcolumn">rightcolumn
<div id="rightcolumn_s">here is div id = rightcolumn_s</div>
</div>
<div class="insidWindow">
    <div id="windowResize" class="ui-wrapper" style="height: 340px; width: 350px;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; " >
            Resize me<br>
            Please try to resizeme:<br> www www www.
        </div>
    </div><br>
    </div><!--insidWindow-->
    <div id="chatRead">here is div id = chatread</div>
    <div id="chatWrite">here is div id = chatWrite</div>
    <div id="lineAzurebotom">here is div id = lineAzurebotom</div>
</div><!--wrapMein-->
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, add `overflow: hidden;` to your `#wrapMein` id.

The additional height (and purple spacing) is coming from the layout your page content is creating from the negative `position: relative` inner divs (-520px etc) which is still counted towards your box model values in Firefox.

Comment: Thanxs but how to slove that overflow: hidden not help me on Firefox.     i use position: relative;
    top: -520px;becose ineed to placit on the correct pace I don't know other option. many thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you trying to remove the large purple section at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Yes i trying to remove the large purple section at the bottom of the page

Comment: Did you try adding overflow: hidden to the #wrapMein CSS? This will remove the large purple section

Comment: Good to hear! Please click on the ✔ (tick) icon as your question has been answered.